# Connect jconsole with mysql 5.1

Tags: java, mysql, jconsole

I want to connect jconsole with mysql 5.1 as likes as database profiler. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JConsole is not a database profiler. It is not a profiler at all. It is just a JMX visualizer. Since each JVM has a "built-in" JMX server you can connect it to any java application. But MySQL is not a java application. It is written in C and compiled to native executable. So JConsole is just irrelevant here.

You can however get access to connection pool and MYSQL JDBC driver if you cannect JConsole to your java application (or application server) that works with MySQL DB.

Comment: I already tested it but i doubt MySQL JDBC driver can show all threads that currently work in MYSQL database.